# From where is The arguments object called inside of an function?

Tags: javascript

When you call object 'arguments' inside of an function, where does this variable come from? So in other words, where is it defined? Lets look with an example:

```js
function func1(a) {
        console.log(arguments[0]);
    }
    
    func1("yellow");
```

I'm gonna make an extreme wild guess here and id say it comes from the static property defined in `func1` since it contains the static property `func1.arguments` but i could be wrong. `func1` however also contains other static properties such as 'length' and 'name' can these be called the same way as shown in the above example?

Comment: [The arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Comment: FYI: arrow functions doesn't have it

Comment: @SimoneRossaini — No. The question is asking about [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) which `Function.arguments` was deprecated in favour of.

Comment: Yes i saw now the different, wrong link :), i correct my comment.

Comment: TBH, the Asker *did* refer to  `func1.arguments`.

Comment: The documentation should be enough to answer this question. Lesson: first check documentation and then ask.

Comment: @trincot that's why I linked the other topic, but actually the example is about something else.

Comment: And now you learned what the arguments is, please do not use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is [defined in the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ordinary-and-exotic-objects-behaviours.html#sec-arguments-exotic-objects).

It is provided by the JS engine when the function is called.

How that is done is an implementation detail of the specific JS engine.

Comment: So what other objects can be called inside of a function besides the arguments object?